# Replacing element in list2 with a random value if the element is in list1

Tags: python-3.x, list

Im trying to do this: if an element of list1 is in list2, that element would have to be replaced with a random element.

It would some something like this:

```
replace(["a","b","c"],"x",["c","n","a","b","l"])
```

And i would have to return this:

```
["x","n","x","x","l"]
```

Comment: Why the second `"a"` and `"b"` aren't replaced in `["c","n","a","b","l"]`?

Comment: My bad, already changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list-comprehension for that.

For example:

```
def replace(lst1, elem, lst2):
    s = set(lst1)
    return [elem if v in s else v for v in lst2]


out = replace(["a", "b", "c"], "x", ["c", "n", "a", "b", "l"])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['x', 'n', 'x', 'x', 'l']
```